# Using Oracle client to connect to remote database

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2

Although I can do a telnet to remote oracle port I am unable to connect.
I have a following **tnsname.ora** connecting to oracle database using sql plus:

```
remoteOracle =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 10.66.1.61)(PORT = 1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVICE_NAME = PROD)
    )
  )
```

**My sqlnet.ora**

```
# sqlnet.ora Network Configuration File: C:\ORACLE\product\11.2.0\client_1\network\admin\sqlnet.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

# This file is actually generated by netca. But if customers choose to 
# install "Software Only", this file wont exist and without the native 
# authentication, they will not be able to connect to the database on NT.

SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES= (NTS)

NAMES.DIRECTORY_PATH= (TNSNAMES, EZCONNECT)
```

When I try to connect using this I always get following error

```
ORA-12504: TNS listener was not given service_name in connect data.
```

And toad shows following error:

```
ORA-12170 TNS connection Time out
```

Comment: Can you try 

    sqlplus hr/hr@OPTPROD

Comment: @AtillaOzgur ORA-12154:
TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified.

Comment: try this sqlplus hr/hr@10.66.1.61:1521/OPTPROD

Comment: @AtillaOzgur What does hr/hr does I am new to oracle please bear with me.

Comment: ora-01015-invalid username/password login denied

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are different ways to connect oracle. One of them is [easy connect](http://www.dba-oracle.com/oracle_news/2006_04_04_connect_using_easy_connect.htm) .

You may use

```
sqlplus username/password@server/SID
```

According to comments. You can connect oracle using easy connect but hr (human resources) account does not exists. 
Therefore try to use

```
sqlplus username/password@10.66.1.61:1521/OPTPROD
```

You should be able to connect your oracle system.

Answer (score 3):

The tnsnames.ora file probably has a syntax problem since you can connect using easy connect. If you want to use tnsnames, I suggest modifying it or recreating it with [Network Configuration Assistant](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/network.112/e10836/admintools.htm#NETAG218).  Full syntax can be found [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/network.112/e10835/tnsnames.htm#NETRF260).

Comment: I did the same.

Comment: I assume you mean that you tried re-creating the tnsnames file with NCA and you still have a problem.  What does TNSPing say for the connection? http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/network.112/e10836/connect.htm#NETAG378

Comment: it has response

Comment: Interesting.  In that case either one of your assumptions is wrong or there is something more complex involved.  If I were you I would re-verify everything and then open a SR with Oracle.

Comment: when I trace with wire shark it says redirection to another IP

Comment: @Kitex Sorry I can't be more help.  You are reaching the limits of my expertise.